# Lilypond: How to use repeat bars in markup lyrics

Tags: lilypond, repeats, lyrics

I am using `\markup` after the score for several verses of lyrics, so roughly

```
\score { ... }
\markup { 
  \column { 
    \line { ... }
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I typeset repeat marks for a piece of lyrics that gets repeated? I tried using `\bar "..."`, `\markup { \bar "..." }`, and I had a look at the various music glyph commands inside markup, but I can't see to find anything suitable.

Answer (score 3):

Lyrics are text, and repeat bars in text are different from repeat bars in music.  Assuming reasonably complete text fonts, probably the simplest expedient is using what is intended for use in text:

```
repL = \markup \char ##X1D106
repR = \markup \char ##X1D107
\markup { \repL This cannot be repeated enough \repR }
```

[image: image of above music]